# VB.Net How do I store lines in a textbox as a variable for later use?

Tags: vb.net

I have a software development assessment which requires me to create a form in which the user can order products. This form looks like this: https://i.imgur.com/48qrsIc.jpg

When adding a product, the product name as well as the quantity, appear in the textbox below like so: https://i.imgur.com/OGzG8Jf.jpg

I want to be able to set each line in the bottom textbox as a variable so I can store it in my database. I don't know if I need to make it an array or a list as I also don't know how to do that.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: If you haven't made an attempt then it's too early to be posting a question here. Do your research, make an honest attempt and then post back here if you have a specific problem. This site is not a place to be taught the fundamentals of development. It's a place to get help with specific coding issues, which you don't have yet because you don't have code.

Comment: See also: [I downvoted because no attempt was made to solve my problem](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/). Provide what you're currently trying and expected result(s).

Comment: Sorry all my apologies, just can't seem to find it anywhere. Thanks though!!! I'll try to figure it out I guess. Sorry for the stupid question...

Comment: not a stupid question. ... you actually did not ask one.

Comment: Oh... I wanted to know if I could pull out text from a textbox line by line and set each line as a variable so if I can input it into ms access database, question being how can I set a line of text in a textbox to be a variable for later use?

Comment: It might be easier to use a Listbox, ListView of DataGridView instead of a textbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never use a control to store data. What you should be doing is have an "Cart" object which is a list of item orders. An item order should be an object which contains the order code, the quantity, and MAYBE the product description.

```
Private Class Product
    Property ProductCode As Integer
    Property Description As String
    Property StockQuantity As Integer
    Property Price As Decimal
End Class

Dim products As New List(Of Product)

Private Class OrderItem
    Public Property ProductCode As Integer
    Public Property Quantity As Integer
End Class

Dim cart As New List(Of OrderItem)
```

And in your combo box, you should bind it to the product list using `Description` as the `.DisplayMember`

When you click the "Add to Cart" button, you can then use the `ComboBox.SelectedItem` which will be the actual product object and add that directly to your cart.

At this point, instead of your data being stored in the RichTextBox, it is stored in a `Cart` object as a list of order items. You can use this list to populate your RichTextBox something like this.

```
Private Sub RefreshRtbOrders()
    RtbOrders.SuspendLayout()
    RtbOrders.Clear()
    For Each item As OrderItem In cart
        RtbOrders.AppendText(item.Quantity.ToString("0000  ") & products.Find(Function(x) x.ProductCode = item.ProductCode).Description & vbCrLf)
    Next
    CboProducts.ResumeLayout()
End Sub
```

You can then use the `Cart` object to update your database.

Comment: Thanks heaps for the response :D I really appreciate it. I'll test it out later and get back to you with any questions!